# SQLAlchemy: Double One-to-One Relationship declaration

Tags: python, database, database-design, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For a database I'm experimenting with, I was advised to change the relationship between `Match` and `Team` from M2M to two 1-to-1 relationships. The logic: There are only two teams for each given match.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to implement this in my `models.py`; here's what I got so far (abridged):

```
class Match(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)


    # One to One x2 with Team
    hometeam_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.id'))
    awayteam_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.id'))
    team = db.relationship("Team", back_populates="match")

    hoemteam_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    awayteam_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

class Team(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    points = db.Column(db.Integer)
    matches_played = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # Many side of M2M With Match
    match = relationship("Match", back_populates="team", uselist=False)
```

There seems to be something missing here, especially in the declaration of `relationship`s in the `Match` side.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add a relationship reference for each one to one relation and use the `foreign_keys` argument of the `relationship`, to specify which id to use:

```
class Match(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)

    # One to One x2 with Team
    hometeam_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.id'))
    awayteam_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.id'))
    hometeam = db.relationship("Team", foreign_keys=[hometeam_id])
    awayteam = db.relationship("Team", foreign_keys=[awayteam_id])

class Team(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    points = db.Column(db.Integer)
    matches_played = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # No backreferences, use a query to figure that out
```

I have removed the `match` relationship as it is not useful here, IMHO.

Relevant documentation is here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#relationship-foreign-keys